# Can't start Celery worker

Tags: python, celery

I have read a bunch of different posts on here about how to get a Celery worker started but it has not worked for me. My file structure is this:

```
    celery_test/
        celeryApp.py
        tasks.py
        run_tasks.py
```

I tried to follow the example here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#next-steps

My command to run was (and yes, I made sure I was in the directory above celery_test/ as specified in the tutorial):

```
    celery -A celery_test worker --loglevel=info
```

And the error I keep getting is:

```
  ImportError: No module named celery_test
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the file `celery_test/__init__.py` (although the requirement [was dropped](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages) in Python 3.3)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I noticed that. I am not to familiar with the whole __init__.py. What do I need to do for that?

Comment: It allows .py files from that directory to be imported.

Comment: @postoronnim I figured it out thankfully. It was that and it was also looking for a celery.py file.